# Plotting of timeseries (ISO8601) in LibreCalc

Tags: libreoffice-calc, date

I have a CSV file with:

```
2020-30-05T23:23    10.000
2020-31-05T09:46    20.000
2020-31-05T13:45    30.000
2020-31-05T19:10    40.000
2020-31-05T23:22    50.000
2020-01-06T09:45    60.000
2020-01-06T17:02    70.000
2020-02-06T06:59    80.000
2020-02-06T18:52    90.000
2020-03-06T09:20    100.000
2020-03-06T17:59    110.000
2020-04-06T06:10    120.000
2020-04-06T17:31    130.000
2020-05-06T10:33    140.000
2020-06-06T10:15    150.000
2020-07-06T15:21    160.000
```

How do I plot those in LibreCalc?

I had expected that I could simply have two columns with the content, but for some reason LibreCalc does not recognize the first column as a date and the seconds as a number.

Answer (score 0):

I have OpenOffice calc and I suggest that the solution is the same for LibreCalc.

Insert a pair of columns between col 1 and col2, add the following code to the first empty column:

> =Left(A1;10)

and to the second column:

> =Right(A1;5)

The data will be created in the two columns limited to only the ten characters of the date and the five characters of the time.